# Get a sub-graph from one node in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

## Context

This is the first time I have to work with *NetworkX* so either I can't read correctly the documentation, or I simply do not use the right vocabulary.

## Problem

I am working with a [DiGraph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html), and I want to get a list of every nodes accessible starting from a specified node.

I thought of making a sub-graph containing the nodes I just described, and I would siply have to iterate over that specific sub-graph. Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to create automatically a sub-graph with the condition I mentioned.

It feels like an obvious feature. What am I missing ?

Comment: In other parts of computer science, one might call this the *reachability* graph. Garbage collectors operate in this way in order to find live/dead objects on the heap. In general graph theory, a directed graph has descendants from a particular node, as Yakym points out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for the `nx.descendants` [method](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.descendants.html):

> descendants(G, source)
>
> Return all nodes reachable from
>   (source) in G.
>
> Parameters :   G : NetworkX DiGraph
>
> source : node in G
>
> Returns :  des : set()
>
> The descendants of source in G